How do you configure a Flowlet as a source in an Azure Data Factory DataFlow
When trying to create a new Azure Data Factory Data Flow one of the options provided is to choose "Flowlet" as the source for the Data Flow.  However when I attempt to do this the Flowlet drop down list is always empty even though I have published Flowlets available.  There is also an incoming stream dropdown in the Flowlet acticity that doesn't seme to make sense since the Flowlet is supposed to be functioning as a source.  Is there some additional configuration required to configure a Flowlet as a source in a an Azure Data Factory Data Flow?
I was expecting a list of published Flowlets to be available on the Flowlet settings tab of the Flowlet activity.

To use Flowlet as source of the dataflow, first you need to create the source in the flowlet. After publishing this flowlet, it will show this in the dataflow source option.
Here, you can see only flowlet1 is showing.

If I want to see flowlet2 here, add source in the flowlet and give your dataset as inline dataset for this.

Add your transformations and output in this flowlet and publish it.
Now, if you check the dataflow Flowlet source, you can see the required flowlet up there in the dropdown.

Here, as this flowlet itself is a source, so no need to give any Incoming stream to it.
For sample, I have used flowlet1 with source and below transformations.

I have added sink file in the dataflow and executed dataflow from the pipeline.
Result file:


Thank you.  Adding a source to the flowlet resolved the issue.  Much appreciated.

Great, it worked for you : ).
